# How to get latest firmware for Linksys Router WRT54G v2

Tags: firmware, wrt54g

I'd like to get the latest firmware for my Linksys WRT54G v2 router, but the linksys page offers no download firmware for this version.

http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT54G

Can I use the one for v3.0 instead which is offered?

If not, which version can I use and is there another source of the firmware other than cisco?

I've got version 2.02.7, perhaps that is already the latest version?

Comment: What is DD-WRT, Alex

Comment: There aren't any updates listed because you already have the latest. Is there a feature you're looking for that you're not finding in your current config?

Comment: @music2myyear Just wanted to make sure I was running the latest firmware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version numbers that Cisco puts on their home WiFi routers is in regard to the hardware used. The WRT54G v2 and the WRT54G v3 (and so on) have different hardware and so the firmware for the v3 may not work correctly on the v2.

If there are no other firmware updates for your specific router on the manufacturer's website, then it is safe to say that you have the most current version.

As far as using other firmware on the device, it is generally not considered a good idea to use non-manufacturer firmware if you want to maintain a stable router. That being said, there are a number of third party alternative firmwares for home routers for those that feel the manufacturer firmware does not offer the features they desire or the stability they need. Some of them are:

- [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com)
- [OpenWRT](http://www.openwrt.org)
- [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)

...and others. Be warned: using any of these will void any warranty you might have on your existing hardware and could "brick" the hardware if not properly installed.

Comment: The V2 is so old, I doubt it is still under warranty.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain : I acknowledge that it's old. However, I prefer to be cautionary when the possibility for the OP to brick his stuff exists. :D

Comment: @Dave M : Thanks for the edit. I suppose I should have been more explicit with that.